# Flowchart (with commenting & versioning) tool for our software process flow - to be reference during development

Tags: software-design, saas, flowchart, development-process

I have recently started learning app development and we are planning make an app + a web based software for storing expense data and all.

Coming to the process flow of the software/app, as a beginner I understand we need a detailed flow charts for every process capturing every possible flow and here are my questions:

1. Does every development process require such an extensive flowcharts? (I had been making apps with rough sketches on papers)
2. What do you suggest a best flowchart tool - Ideally I am thinking it should be able to capture comments, images etc. for every flow and history feature to see what was the flow before and why we changed it (looked at whimsical, draw.io, visio and mind mapping tools)
3. Can we make a user guide from this flowchart itself as these charts are going to show every possible flow.

Appreciate your help guys. Thank You.